# Tensorflow import

Tags: python, tensorflow

Whenever I try to import tensorflow for gpu, this problem arises.
please help.
I have NVIDIA GTX 1080 gpu.

---

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\site-     packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py
", line 58, in <module>

from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_in
ternal.py", line 28, in <module>

_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_in
ternal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper

_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

---

Comment: how did you install tensorflow?

Comment: You seem to be using Anaconda. Did you install it within an environment, and if so, was it via pip or conda?

Comment: I Used pip, installed both tf-nighty-gpu and tensorflow-gpu

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are running on Windows, try to install below:

```
conda install cudatoolkit
conda install cudnn
```

Can you check cudnn 7.x and cuda 9.0 are installed?